# Error on "pod install --verbose"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I just installed pod with this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

git cloned a project from git repository and run `pod install --verbose` and I get this error:

[image]

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to integrate the following embedded targets with their respective host targets (a host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target like a framework or extension):

- MyApp (true) and OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (false) do not both set use_frameworks!.
```

I can't get this app tower inside Xcode because of this. I get this error message:

[image]

#### update

this is my (the only one) Podfile

[image]

#### update 2

after putting up the use_frameworks! line I get this:

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like the problem is that your app is setting `use_frameworks`.

Comment: yes I have that line inside Podfile. I just need to make some changes to this app and I can't get it to run in xcode

Comment: If I do a plain vanilla Podfile, I can include both of those pods and `pod install` works great for me.  I wonder if it's something else about your Podfile that causes this issue to happen.  Could you edit your question to show your Podfile?

Comment: updated with screenshot from podfile

Comment: try moving `use_frameworks!` up and out of only one target (i.e. move it up three lines in the Podfile), so that it applies to all targets.

Comment: OK will try it now

Comment: updated with screenshot for use_frameworks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay!

Looks like the solution in your case was to move `use_frameworks!` up and out of a specific target and make it global for the Podfile.

The issues you're now seeing (in your Update 2) is that you need to go into your Project Settings and fix the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` setting.  I'd recommend simply removing the build setting.

Comment: I still have errors :( can't get it to compile. I install everything and now i get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243053/apple-mach-o-linker-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-command-1

Comment: I had the same error because I was using a forked project and someone put `use_frameworks!` inside of a target in the pod file. This fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

add use_frameworks! to solve this problem on OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.

`target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.5.2', '< 3.0'
end`

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the use_frameworks! line globally.
It worked for me!!!

Sample Code below :

use_frameworks!

target 'my_project' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end